# Mono addin doesn't load if initialized from autocad

Tags: c#, plugins, autocad-plugin, mono.addins

I've a quite complex application, this application is structured like so:

`Main.exe` (is a standalone application)

`Main.exe` uses `Project1.dll` (which contains a form)

the form contained inside the `Project1.dll` is extended by another dll (`Project2.dll`) using `mono.addins`

In `Main.exe` I can see the form extended in the correct way.

I've also implemented an autocad connector (say `Project3.dll`) which is loaded via `netload` inside autocad, this connector uses the form of `Project1.dll` and that form has to be extended also in autocad.

The result is that inside autocad my form appears not extended, and if I debug the code:

```
        AddinManager.Initialize();
        AddinManager.Registry.Update(null);

        foreach (IMyPlugin Addin in AddinManager.GetExtensionObjects(typeof(IMyPlugin)))
        {
            if (Addin.IsPluginLicensed)
                EmbedPlugin(Addin);
        }
```

the foreach doesn't yield any addin.

Notice that each of those .dll are stored in the same directory.

I suppose that the problem resides in the different location of the autocad exe file but I've tried some tweaks and none works..

I've tried:

- create an .addins file that contains the .dlls path.
- create a subfolder \addins\ with a copy of all the .dlls
- initialize the `AddinManager` giving the .dll path
- update the `AddinManager.Registry` giving the .dll path

the code structure is quite complex (involves many files and projects) so is not so easy to paste or give some working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem. `Mono.Addins` was loaded from `LoadFrom` context and this has led to a DllHell problem. Manually loading `Mono.Addins` like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13515573/838405) solved the problem.