# nonsense argument exception calling method

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, exception, 64-bit, autocad

I'm receiving an ArgumentException "Object type cannot be converted to target type" but it doesn't make very sense to me.[image: You can see the exception in this image]

the method I'm calling has the following signature:

```
public void Scan(IProgressStatus monitor, string registryPath, string startupDir, string addinsDir, string databaseDir, string scanFolder, string[] filesToIgnore)
```

I tried to pass `monitor` instead of `remMonitor` but the exception is still thrown.
All the arguments have values except `scanFolder` that is null (but passing string.Empty still throw exception) and `filesToIgnore` is a zero-length array.

I can't figure out why the exception is thrown.

Don't know if it helps but the process is 64 bit. If I call the same method from a 32 bit process no exception are thrown and it runs well.

**[EDIT]** If I pass null instead of remMonitor it enters the method.

**[EDIT2]** Debugging more deeply I found something strange. I've tried to box-unbox the parameter:

```
rsd.Scan((object)remMonitor, registry.RegistryPath, registry.StartupDirectory, registry.DefaultAddinsFolder, registry.AddinCachePath, scanFolder, filesToIgnore);
```

and

```
public void Scan(object monitor, string registryPath, string startupDir, string addinsDir, string databaseDir, string scanFolder, string[] filesToIgnore)
{
    monitor = (IProgressStatus)monitor;
```

The result is:

```
?(IProgressStatus)monitor
Cannot cast 'monitor' (which has an actual type of 'System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.__TransparentProxy') to 'Mono.Addins.IProgressStatus'
```

It looks like that monitor has actually an incompatible type, now the question is why?

**[EDIT3]** Ok I've managed to understand that it's a DllHell load context problem, I've turn on all the Exceptions inside Visual Studio and it says that Mono.Addins is load in a LoadFrom context. But if I write the instruction `Assembly.Load("Mono.Addins");` the same warning (loaded from LoadFrom context) is thrown. Some hints?

Comment: I guess the problem is inside Scan method. Is it a method you wrote yourself ? This is likely due to some reflection error

Comment: if I press "step into" the exception is thrown before it enters inside the method body, so I think that the problem is somewhere in the argument types. I don't write the method by myself, this is mono.addins source code: http://monoaddins.codeplex.com/releases/view/96359

Comment: Have you tried looking at the StackTrace of the exception?

Comment: this is the stack trace:
   
at Mono.Addins.Database.RemoteSetupDomain.Scan(IProgressStatus monitor, String registryPath, String startupDir, String addinsDir, String databaseDir, String scanFolder, String[] filesToIgnore)
  

 at Mono.Addins.Database.SetupDomain.Scan(IProgressStatus monitor, AddinRegistry registry, String scanFolder, String[] filesToIgnore) in d:\Desktop\Mono.Addins-source-1.0\Mono.Addins\Mono.Addins.Database\SetupDomain.cs:line 44

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to format it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've managed to solve my problem:

As written in EDIT3 it was a load context problem, [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57143.aspx) explains quite well the loading behavior for each method.

Accordingly to [this hint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172214.aspx) I've manually loaded the assembly using:

```
        System.Reflection.AssemblyName an = new System.Reflection.AssemblyName();
        an.Name = "Mono.Addins";
        an.Version = new System.Version(1, 0, 0);
        System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(an);
```

Then I've placed the right assembly `Mono.Addins.dll` inside the `AutoCAD.exe` path (that is the `ApplicationBase` for my application). Originally I thought that the `ApplicationBase` was the same path of the calling assembly but was not, FYI to discover the Application base path I've used `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;`

Answer (score 0):

Found this over in a Google Group, and it mentions the same exception on the same method:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mono-addins/f4SzNPtcRIg/ma9EPEzGdagJ

> In SetupDomain.cs:Scan() there is a line that reads: rsd.Scan
>   (remMonitor, registryPath, startupDir, scanFolder, filesToIgnore);
>
> If I step into this method I'm not taken to the Scan() method, but
>   instead RemoteProgressStatus:InitializeLifetimeService() which returns
>   null.  After returning from that method the exeption is thrown.
>
> Is this a known problem and perhaps a work around?  Thanks!
>
> System.ArgumentException occurred   Message="Object type cannot be
>   converted to target type."   Source="Mono.Addins"   StackTrace:
>          at Mono.Addins.Database.RemoteSetupDomain.Scan(IProgressStatus monitor, String registryPath, String startupDir, String scanFolder,
>   String[] filesToIgnore)
>          at Mono.Addins.Database.SetupDomain.Scan(IProgressStatus monitor, String registryPath, String startupDir, String scanFolder,
>   String[] filesToIgnore) in C:\Users\Kiel\Projects\Mono.Addins
>   \Mono.Addins\Mono.Addins.Database\SetupDomain.cs:line 43
>   InnerException:
>
> Solution:
>
> I moved AddinManager.Initialize(); and
>   AddinManager.Registry.Update(null); to a method marked
>   [ClassInitialize] versus trying to do this in the constructor and
>   things are happy again.

Comment: no luck, still the same error. My project is not a test project, so maybe something similar to [ClassInitialize] for normal projects should works? I don't know what does ClassInitialize..